# Natural Language Processing for Abstract and Concrete Text?

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet

I'm looking for a tool/wordlist that can identify [abstract](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/nlpdict.html#abstractnoun) and [concrete](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/nlpdict.html#concretenoun) adjectives and nouns. The closest thing I've found is Euro Wordnet, which identifies entities. [First word entities](http://www.illc.uva.nl/EuroWordNet/corebcs/ewnTopOntology.html) are concrete in nature. Second and third levels are abstract. However, Euro Wordnet is not free, and the wordlist is over a decade old.

Anyone done this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concreteness ratings for 40 thousand English lemmas:
  http://crr.ugent.be/archives/1330
(free for non-commercial use)

There are lists here (but I cannot find a license - if you track one down, please let us know!):
  http://www.l2f.inesc-id.pt/~abarreiro/openlogos-tutorial/NOUNroot.htm